# Bootstrap navbar dropdown menu positioning

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am designing a website.In my site I want to create such a menu where navbar  will contain such a **ul** which class will be **nav navbar-nav navbar-right**.After shrinking the page size,when the dropdown button will appear.Then if the user click the button,in the appeared dropdown menu the li item should be float left,that means **ul** class will be **nav navbar-nav navbar-left**.How can I do this?I tried jquery.But in that case,the **ul** is not returning to its original **nav navbar-nav navbar-right** class after the page is returning to its original size.Here is an example of a website-

http://preview.themeforest.net/item/riana-charity-html-template/full_screen_preview/12694958

```
<header class="header">

      <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
    </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">


      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right"> <!--This ul class should be changed,when the dropdown button is clicked. -->
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>

      </ul>
    </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>

      </header>
```

Using the Jquery

```
$('.navbar-toggle').click(function(){
$('#dropdown').removeClass('nav navbar-nav navbar-right');      
$('#dropdown').addClass('nav navbar-nav navbar-left');  
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to add navbar-right class and remove navbar-left class on window resize

```
$(window).resize(function(){
    if($(window).width () > 767) { // media query break point
       $('#dropdown').removeClass('navbar-left');      
       $('#dropdown').addClass('navbar-right');  
    } 
});
```

You can also achieve this only with CSS